# Maxing out gear with maxed out smithing, enchanting and alchemy

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have level 100 smithing, enchanting and alchemy. I also have some nice enchanted gear, fortify smithing and alchemy.

How high should I be able to get my fortified equipment? 
Currently I'm around 29% for alchemy and smithing.

How high can I get fortify smithing and fortify enchanting potions without using the console (cheating)? And how?
Currently I get +147% and +32% respectively.

Is something like this possible without using the console(or photoshop)?
[image: Photoshop much?]

Comment: I can not comment on everything but I do recall the cap for %less was I think 25%, so you can achieve 100% reduction, but you need to put that enchantment on 4 pieces of gear.

Comment: You can get to at least 29%. I have 3 items with a total of -106% destruction (I should be making magika when I can a fireball)

Comment: I have tried playing skyrim without using my console, trust me you need to turn the Xbox on first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

29% is the max cap you can get per piece of armor via the in game fortify loop.  I've tried using the falmer helmet glitch to see if I can boost my enchanting up some more, but it does not.  The only way you can make that armor with a fully patched game is using the console.

However, there used to be a glitch with fortify restoration that can turbo boost your skills to insane levels, and with that it was possible to make armor as shown in the picture.

Comment: You mention 'Used to be a glitch with fortify restoration'. This looks to be alive and well as of this date in the game to me. I do not think it could give you the stats on the armor of the question however as the parts do not add up to any enchantment set or pair I have seen as of yet.

Comment: @James maybe that video didn't explain it properly and I picked a bad one as an example.  There used to be a way (maybe its still not patched) to form a complete feedback loop via fortify restoration that can easily allow you to make 100% reduction armor.  See here as an example: http://skyrimforums.org/threads/infinite-fortify-restoration-exploit.3116/

Comment: Oh, sorry miss-communication on my part. I just did not think those two stats looked right together. I know you could get it to 100% reduction, but I did not think you could do that and only have a 10% regeneration along side it. I used a Fortify Restoration potion to increase my smith skill just 3 days ago now so it is still active :)

Comment: @James ah, I see.  The enchantment on that armor is correct, its the one from robes and the magic regen is fixed at 10% (possibly a bug)

Comment: You can get to 41% with Azhidal's gear and bonuses to Alchemy and Enchanting from the Sallow Regent Black Book (requires Dragonborn DLC).

Answer (score 4):

That glitch you used is still available and can be used...but what you should do is wear fortify alchemy equipment, make the fortify restoration potion, drink, unequip/equip clothing, repeat till your gear is ridiculously high, fortify alchemy, then make a fortify enchanting potion and set enchantments on other equipment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Dragonborn DLC, you can wear the armor of Ahzidal from Unearthed to give your enchanting a 10% boost. And the Black Book: The Sallow Regent will give your enchanting another 10% boost if you choose Seeker of Sorcery. When you're ready to begin making potions, just wear your Fortify Alchemy gear and read The Sallow Regent once again, this time choosing Seeker of Shadows for a 10% boost to your Alchemy.

Without exploits, my circlet tops out at 70% Archery/43% Alchemy.

---

Comment: A more thorough answer is here:  http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting#Maximizing_Enchantment_Power.  If you format the answer better and include all the proper steps, it might attract more upvotes :)

Comment: Ahzidal's Armor set adds +10 to your Enchanting skill, not a 10% boost(they are different). Example:I have 100 Enchanting. I put on Ahzidal's Armor set and enter the Enchanting interface(Enchanting table) and my skill is 110. I leave the interface and take an enchanting potion(says enchantments are 40% stronger, but it actually raises your skill by the number listed in the percentage). I reenter the interface and now have 150 skill. 100 skill is 25% boost on its own. With 150 skill and Seeker of Sorcery from black book Sallow Regent (buffs enchants by 10%) my enchantments are ~ 40% stronger.

Answer (score -2):

Enchant your initial gear, should be 25% each on alchemy. Head piece, arms, necklace, ring. Then craft a fortify enchanting potion, which should be 25% or more. Then get 4 more of the essential pieces use potion and it'll increase the gear over the 25% gap. Rinse and repeat til your satisfied with the result. It takes more time and grinding than the restoration glitch, but in all fairness, having ten trillion damage and armor rating makes the game too easy, especially since your practically enough of a god as is at high enough levels. After over 600 hours I've gotten to level 251 without any glitches and have a set of gear with + 103% alchemy and blacksmithing(tried getting exactly 100% but oh well) works wonders too if you're a poisoner and like to throw in a few frenzies to conserve Magicka.

Answer (score -5):

## This Guide is for players who play with a patch bigger than 1.9!

**Hello there :D**

I did a lot of research from many sources and was a bit confused how less actual information I found, so I investet many hours finding the way to the strongest weapons (max. Damage).

> #### Very important note:
>
> *I don't use any exploits here, that's cheating in my opinion. The part with the necromage has never been fixed by the developers (while a lot of other stuff has changed) and in my opinion, it's nothing false about it.*

I'll give you a little step-by-step here. You'll find optional information at the end. Note that I did this with Level 74 so I'm looking to keep this guide as small in perk-wasting as possible (without any loss!). For me, I always leveled the whole perk-trees.

*Feel free to share this Guide or to turn it into a video. It would be nice, if you'd name me there, but it's ok, if you don't. :)*

Another note: This guide bases on the complete Skyrim edition (Dawnguard, Heartfire and Dragonborn).

## **Let's start:**

### Pre-condition:

- **Minimum of 22 free Perks** *[if the aren't already invested in the following points]*.
- **Restoration Level 70**
- **Alchemy Level 80**
- **Smithing Level 100** *[At least 91, if you don't want to make a weapon out of dragonbone! But it'll be the strongest ones!]*
- **Enchanting Level 80** *[100 highly recommended because of the "Extra Effect" Perk!]*
- You need **multiple unenchanted Helmets, Gauntlets, Necklages, Rings** (random stuff, value/material is not important!)
- **As much as you have of the following ingredients** *[see part 6 + 10 for details]*
  - Blisterwort
  - Glowing Mushroom
  - Sabre Cat Tooth
  - Spriggan Sap
  - Ancestor Moth Wing
  - Blue Butterfly Wing
  - Chaurus Hunter Antennae
  - Hagraven Claw
  - Snowberries
  - Spawn Ash

**Must have-Perks:**

- Restoration: Necromage
- Alchemy: Alchemist 5/5 + Benefactor
- Enchanting: Enchanter 5/5 + Insightful Enchanter
- Smithing: Daedric Smithing + Dragon Smithing (best Heavy Armor: Daedric, strongest Weapons: Dragon)

### Process:

1. Craft the weapon(s)/Armor(s) of your confidence using a "Blacksmith Forge" (Important: Crafting the weapons doesn't need a potion or some enchanted gear! At this point, this does absolutely nothing!). The best/strongest weapons are the one from the Dragonbones/Dragonscales! The best Heavy Armor is the Daedric.
2. Become a vampire.
3. Goto an "Enchanting Table".
4. Enchant the following stuff with "Fortify Alchemy":

   - Helmet
   - Braces
   - Necklage
   - Ring

   Equip theese and goto an "Alchemy Table"

   Put 2 of the following items together (your choice) to craft a "Fortify Enchanting Potion":

   - Ancestor Moth Wing
   - Blue Butterfly Wing
   - Chaurus Hunter Antennae
   - Hagraven Claw
   - Snowberries
   - Spawn Ash
   - Spriggan Sap

   Craft the potion, go to an enchanting table, ***drink it*** and repeat this from part 4 until you have this item-stats:

   - Fortify Enchanting Potion: 38%
   - Fortify Alchemy Helmet/Gauntlets/Necklage/Ring: 31%

   Equip your 31% alchemy gear.

   Craft as many possible "Fortify Enchanting Potions"! *[Look at part 6]*

   Craft as many possible "Fortify Smithing" Potions using again 2 of the following ingredients:

   - Blisterwort
   - Glowing Mushroom
   - Sabre Cat Tooth
   - Spriggan Sap

   Go to the "Enchanting Table" and drink one of the "Fortify Enchanting Potions" *[remember the timelimit of the potion]*.

   **Enchant the following items with "Fortify Smithing":**

   - Helmet
   - Braces
   - Necklage
   - Ring

   Grab the weapon of your confidence and search a gridstone

   Drink one of the "Fortify Smithing" Potions *[remember the timelimit of the potion]* and improve your weapon/armor! :)

   You now have the strongest possible weapon, but don't forget: By improving other Armor with enchants like "Fortify One-Handed", etc. you can take out a lot more Damage! But the weapon itself is now on the highest possible level! Enchant other gear with your "Fortify Enchanting Potions".

## Serious tips:

#### Best equippment in each category:

- Heavy Armor: Daedric
- Light Armor: Dragonscale
- Weapons: Dragonbone
- Sneaking: Non-Armor clothes

#### Maximum possible stats for each stuff:

- Fortify Enchanting Potion: 38%
- Fortify Alchemy Gear: 31%
- Fortify Smithing Gear: 31%
- Fortify Smithing Potion: 153%

#### How to become a vampire?

Videos:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoXEf-oY1hY
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRs-qlkhnmA

#### How to cure from vampirism and turn back to normality

Go to Morthal and talk to the mage called Falion. He will cure you, if you bring him a filled "Black Sould Gem" (if you have an empty one, the easiest way would be to cast a weapon, "Bound Bow" for example, and shoot a Human to death! This will capture his soul in the Soul Gem).

#### I'm already cured! Help! I wanna turn back into a vampire!

Easy, just go to "Castle Volkihar" and talk to "Serana", she'll help you.

#### Where can I find "Daedra Hearts"?

Go to Winterhold and talk to "Enthir" (he's somewhere in the college). He will sell you 2. After you bought them, wait 2 days or safe the game and restart it, to refill his stock. You can repeat this until you die.

#### For what's the Necromage-Perk?!

It improves the spells on undeads. Now if you turn into a vampire, you also turn into an undead, so this point also counts on you. Potions ans gear are also in the category "Spells", which improves them also. :)
Nobody seems to be sure if this is a bug or if it's wanted like this by the developers. It doesn't sound to me like this was a planned feature at the beginning, but it make sense and it also gives you a reason to play as vampire. Vampires are generally underpowered in Skyrim.

#### Tell me everyting about crafting and improvement!

- **Workbench:** Imrpove Armor
- **Grindstone:** Improve Weapons
- **Tanning Rack:** Turn pelts into Leather
- **Smelter:** Turn ores into ingots (2 ores = 1 ingot)
- **Blacksmith Forge:** Craft weapons, armor, jewellry, building materials
- **Alchemy Table:** For Alchemy-Potions (hoho...srsly?)
- **Enchanting Table:** Enchanting gear

Comment: Note that killing a human with a bound weapon will only capture his soul with the appropriate Perk in Conjuration.

Comment: In its current form, this answer doesn't make the answers to the specific questions asked easy to find.  A more concise answer that covers just the basics and perhaps references an external guide would be preferable to a general guide.

Comment: You have a big explanation, but this answer is indeed wrong since this doesn't do very much then usual. Just as @agent86 said.

Comment: "Very important note:
I don't use any exploits here, that's cheating in my opinion. The part with the necromage has never been fixed by the developers (while a lot of other stuff has changed) and in my opinion, it's nothing false about it." Um, you just did an exploit in this guide and besides it isn't cheating at all. The exploit you're doing is fortify alchemy and enchanting exploit.

Comment: Besides, does a vampire have any ability at all? We already know about crafting and improvement, and also you explained that you need the following skills at a high level. But what about for beginners? You even mentioned that you need DLCs too, but what you only mentioned that has to do with the DLC is turning back into a vampire, not anything else at all!

Comment: @Jim What exploit is it you're talking about? PS: A beginner cannot "get" the best weapon of course. :) And you need the Dawnguard-DLC to do that.

Comment: @TrudleR this is why you're answer is downvoted alright now? Enough!

Comment: The worst guide I've ever seen!

Comment: @Jim: No, my answer isn't specific, that's why. But thx. I hope you actually try to do something yourself for the community. Not just walking around pretending you know everything better. :) I have a hard time right now to accept your critics because it sounds like from a whiny little kid somehow. "I don't understand so it's the WORST I've ever seen!!!1", lol.

Comment: All right. Just please make your guide better and you'll get good votes.

Comment: Have fun on your "exploit".

Comment: This could be clearer, for sure, and definitely a lot shorter, but if the vampire thing works like you say it does then that's a useful addition worth an upvote.