# Enchanting/Alchemy without 5/5 alchemy?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> Create a 4 pieces of Fortify Alchemy Equipment (hat, gloves, necklace, ring)
>
> With the clothing on, create some (4) Fortify Enchanting Potions
>
> Create a new, stronger set of Fortify Alchemy Clothing by drinking those potions.
>
> With the Stronger Set, Create some new Fortify Enchanting Potions (they're stronger as the previous ones.)
>
> Now you'll create your Final set of Fortify Achemy Equipment (hat, gloves, necklace, ring) under influence of those stronger potions.
>
> You now can use this Fortify Achemy set to create as many Fortify Enchanting Potions as you need to improve your other stuff.

Is it possible to get this effect without having 5/5 enchanting? What if you just make more potion rounds? Like instead of 3 alchemy clothing, you make even more?

Answer (score 9):

Fortify potions in Skyrim DO NOT STACK.

If you already are under the effects of a fortify enchantment from a potion effect, and you drink another one, you will not benefit from both fortify enchantments.  (I am unsure if the old one is blown away or the new one is ignored, but you will definitely not benefit from both.)

The reason why you want 5/5 enchanting is to allow you to make the armor set with the highest possible fortify alchemy.  The reason why the instructions asks you to make multiple fortify enchanting potions is because time does not freeze while you are enchanting your armor.  If you take too long, you will have to use another enchanting potion.

The best potion you can make in the game requires 5 armor pieces:

- Falmer Helmet (There is a glitch where you can wear both a falmer helmet and circlet at the same time)
- circlet of some kind
- gloves
- ring
- necklace

You will also need all 5 alchemist perks as well as the welfare perk.  To make the highest set of alchemy armor, you will need the 5 enchanter perks, and the insightful enchanter perk.

Here are some more questions that may help you:

- [Maxing out gear with maxed out smithing enchanting and alchemy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45827/maxing-out-gear-with-maxed-out-smithing-enchanting-and-alchemy/45831#45831)
- [Fortify alchemy fortify enchant stacking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36692/fortify-alchemy-fortify-enchant-stacking)
- [How do I create Fortify Alchemy enchantments up to 29%?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39923/how-do-i-create-fortify-alchemy-enchantments-up-to-29)

Comment: i would argue falmer helmet is a bug just like infinite restoration stacking

Answer (score 1):

You can do any of this without the noted perks, but the effect will be that much less potent. You won't, for example, make it up to +29% buffs on your gear.

The perks make a big difference.