# Skyrim: Is there a percentage cap to the alchemy/enchanting fortification loop?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maxing out gear with maxed out smithing, enchanting and alchemy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45827/maxing-out-gear-with-maxed-out-smithing-enchanting-and-alchemy)

With 4 pieces of +28% fortify alchemy gear, I was able to create a +32% fortify enchantment potion.  I was then able to use that potion to create 4 pieces of +29% fortify alchemy gear.  However, using the new gear, I was still only to create another +32% fortify enchantment potion.

At first, I thought that it was just rounding down to the nearest whole number for display purposes and that it was actually 32.xx% behind the scenes.  However, I don't think this is the case.  Usually, when items are distinctly different in any way, they group separately in the inventory screen, but the +32% potion I created with the +29% alchemy gear groups in with the other fortify enchantment potions that I previously created with the +28% gear, so I am assuming there's no change.

I hear there's a fortify restoration exploit, but I don't want to use that.  Basically, I just want to know if +32% is the most I am going to get from a fortify enchantment potion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game has a built-in max to prevent infinitely high bonuses to equipment.

Here's a great post on maxing damage in Skyrim:
http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1266212-2469-armor-3199-damage-using-smithing-alchemy-enchanting-only-31-perks/

Comment: I am right where that guy is at the "33 Perks Total" section with Daedric 2H sword at 210.  However, I can't figure out how he got to 605 at the next section.  Do you know what is meant by "4 X Weapon Enchants and 4 X Armor Enchants"?

Comment: I just verified my above comment.  He was most likely referring to using the dual enchanting perk to enchant 4 pieces of gear with fortify 1H/2H and 4 pieces of gear with fortify light/heavy armor.  I did this and the only thing I can't kill in one hit right now are dragons, drauger death lords and their ilk, and Forsworn Briarhearts.