# Fortify Enchanting Recipe?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What is the recipe for "Fortify Enchanting"?

I was hoping to try and do some glitches, and get my alchemy to 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends which DLCs you have. According to [UESP](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fortify_Enchanting) you'll want **any two** of the following:

- Ancestor Moth Wing (Dawnguard)
- Blue Butterfly Wing
- Chaurus Hunter Antennae (Dawnguard)
- Dreugh Wax (Creation Club)
- Hagraven Claw
- Snowberries
- Spawn Ash (Dragonborn)
- Spriggan Sap
- Stoneflower Petals (Creation Club)

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45827/maxing-out-gear-with-maxed-out-smithing-enchanting-and-alchemy) may also be useful.